Amide group nucleophilic attack pi or lone pair electrons?
I am confused about the drawing of a mechanism in the solutions to the textbook problems to chapter 10 from the Clayden Organic Chemistry textbook:

Why is  the electron arrow in the second step starting from the nitrogen-carbon double bond? Shouldn’t the arrow start from the lone pair on the nitrogen as the lone pair is higher in energy (And therefore the HOMO) because it isn’t conjugated like the double bond pi electrons:


It is the pi-electrons of the carbamate enolate that are the nucleophile, not the non-bonding electrons on nitrogen. BTW: The double-headed arrow means addition-elimination.

And why are the Pi electrons the nucleophile instead of the lone pair on Nitrogen? I thought the LUMO always reacts with the HOMO, and isn't the HOMO the nitrogen lone pair as it is higher in energy than the Pi electrons?
